# How do I upload an image file using MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

Im trying to us a controller in MVC2 to upload a file but i get an object reference not set to an instance of an object error

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPhoto(int id, FormCollection formValues, HttpPostedFile image, AlbumPhotos photo )
    {            
        AlbumPhoto photos = new AlbumPhoto();
        UserPhotoAlbum album = AlbumRepo.GetAlbum(id);
        photo.AlbumId = id;
        photos.AlbumId = photo.AlbumId;
        photo.PostedDate = DateTime.Now;
        photos.PostedDate = photo.PostedDate;
        album.LastUpdate = photo.PostedDate;

        if (image.FileName != null)
        {
            photo.PhotoMimeType = image.ContentType;
            photos.PhotoMimeType = image.ContentType;
            photo.PhotoData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
            photos.PhotoData = photo.PhotoData;
            image.InputStream.Read(photo.PhotoData, 0, image.ContentLength);
            photo.PhotoUrl = "../../Content/UserPhotos/" + image.FileName;
            photos.PhotoUrl = photo.PhotoUrl;
            image.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UserPhotos/" + image.FileName));
        }

        AlbumRepo.AddPhotoToAlbum(photos);
        AlbumRepo.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Album", new { id = photo.AlbumId });
    }
```

Please tell me if i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: which line are you getting the error?

Comment: don't type your title all in capitals - it is considered to be shouting and impolite.

Comment: that's why i edited it for him. :)

Comment: Make sure the `<form>` tag has a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` property set. Otherwise it won't post.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to ensure the `<form> tag has a enctype="multipart/form-data"` value in the object htmlAttribute paramter of `Html.BeginForm()`
2. The name of the input file control should match the name of the parameter passed into the `[HttpPost]` Action method.

e.g.

```
<input type="file" name="uploadControl" />
```

should match 'name-wise' to:

```
public ActionResult AddPhoto(int id, FormCollection formValues, HttpPostedFile uploadControl, AlbumPhotos photo)
```

See http://www.277hz.co.uk/Blog/Show/7/image-uploading-in-asp-net-mvc for a good explanation.

Comment: If you prefer to use `Html.BeginForm()` over straight HTML tags you can do this to avoid having to specify the controller, action, etc (useful when reusing the view in multiple places): `Html.BeginForm(null, null, null, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })`.

Comment: When linking to your blog, please mention that you're linking to your blog in some way.  Otherwise it might be considered as spam.